# Java Syntax confusion, why put () around a class?

Tags: java, syntax

I'm studying Prototype Design pattern I can't understand the syntax below. Can you explain it to me? What does it mean for a class to be put in parentheses and initialized like this :

```
Person person2 = (Person) person1.doSomthing();
```

Code in context:

```
// code in  int main
Person person1 = new Person("Fred");// this is understood
    System.out.println("person 1:" + person1);// this is understood
    Person person2 = (Person) person1.doClone();//not understood
    System.out.println("person 2:" + person2);// this is understood
```

Is this syntax in java for casting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a cast. In other words, the `doSomething()` method is most likely not declared to return a `Person`. So you need to first cast the returned value to a `Person` before assigning it to `person2`.

If `doSomething` does return a `Person`, then the cast is not necessary.

And if the actual type of the object returned by `doSomething` is not assignable to a Person, the cast will throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime.

More info about it in the [JLS #15.16](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16):

> A cast expression converts, at run-time, a value of one numeric type to a similar value of another numeric type; or confirms, at compile-time, that the type of an expression is boolean; or checks, at run-time, that a reference value refers to an object whose class is compatible with a specified reference type.
>
> The parentheses and the type they contain are sometimes called the cast operator.

Answer (score 4):

It's called [type casting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion). What you are saying is that you want to ensure that the JVM makes an attempt to force whatever type of object is returned by that call to be a `Person`.

Another thing not mentioned by assylias is that this has two additional features:

1. If the actual returned object is a subclass of `Person`, it will change the returned value into a `Person`. This can be useful for when you want to make sure that whatever subclass is actually used, it'll hopefully behave just like a `Person`.
2. If `Person` is an interface, it will let you step outside of the inheritance hierarchy of that particular implementation altogether and use someone else's `Person` implementation. This is great for use with APIs like Spring which let you configure after build time how classes are chained together in things like security configurations and such.

Answer (score 2):

It is simply used to cast it (`person1.doSomthing()`) into `Person` type. Because it may not be returning a `Person` type, but something that can be casted into a `Person` type.

Comment: +1 for being first and not repeating what everyone else is saying

Answer (score 1):

You're casting the result of `Person.doClone()` to also be of type `Person`. Presumably `Person.doClone()` returns an `Object` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

```
Person person2 = (Person) person1.doSomthing();
```

It Type casting to Person type which Object returns from person1.doSomthing().

```
Person person2 = (Person) person1.doClone();
```

Here it clone the person1 Object cast it into person object.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typecast, to ensure that the object type that is returned from calling `person1.doClone()` is of type `Person`, so that it can be assigned to your person2 variable.

If the `doClone()` method is defined in the `Person` class, I would expect it to return an object of type `Person`.  In this scenario, the cast is benign and unnecessary.

However, `doClone()` may be defined in a superclass of `Person`, and returning a more generic type, thus a narrowing cast may be desired.

If `doClone` does not return an instance of type `Person` (or some other class in Person's inheritance hierarchy), then a `java.lang.ClassCastException` will be thrown.